# How to specify starting point of tf.Data.iterator (or skipping first X batches)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

For a tensorflow dataset iterator (tf.data.Iterator), what is the best way of skipping over the first X batches, but ONLY in the first iteration, and not for subsequent iterations when repeat() is specified)?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').config("spark.jars",'some/path/spark-tensorflow-connector_2.11-1.10.0.jar').getOrCreate()

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(10), 'y': [i*2 for i in range(10)]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.write.format('tfrecords').option('recordType', 'Example').mode("overwrite").save('testdata')

def parse_function(proto):
    feature_description = {
    'x': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'y': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, feature_description)

    x = parsed_features['x']
    y = parsed_features['y']

    return {'x': x, 'y': y}

def load_data(filename_pattern, parse_function, batch_size=200, skip_batches=0):
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=filename_pattern, shuffle=False)
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)

    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size))

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)

    # Create an iterator
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    data = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in range(skip_batches):
            sess.run(data)

    return data

# skip first three batches
data = load_data('testdata/part-*', parse_function, batch_size=2, skip_batches=3)

sess = tf.Session()

for i in range(3):
    print(sess.run(data))
```

Expected/desired:

```
    {'y': array([12, 14]), 'x': array([6, 7])}
    {'y': array([16, 18]), 'x': array([8, 9])}
    {'y': array([0, 2]), 'x': array([0, 1])}
```

Actual:

```
    {'y': array([0, 2]), 'x': array([0, 1])}
    {'y': array([4, 6]), 'x': array([2, 3])}
    {'y': array([8, 10]), 'x': array([4, 5])}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going through the `tf.Dataset.iterator()`, why don't you skip the first X batches?

Let's say you want 10 Batches and each has 32 elements, means total 320 elements. So you can skip these using `tf.Dataset.skip(320)` ([skip](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip)) which gives you dataset with first 10 Batches skipped.